# Can't make my python package print output

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging, function-call

I recently created and published my own hello_world package for learning purposes, since I'm new to this I am having some issue getting the hello_world output. The link of the repo is:

https://github.com/fanik041/fsa_hello_world_package

In the `cli.py` file I wrote two functions for hello_world:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def hello():
    """ Returns a Hello, World! """
    return("Hello, World!")


def say_hello():
    """Prints Hello, World again! """
    print(hello())
```

But when I try to call the function `hello()` or `say_hello()` (after installing the package) the IDE can't find the functions. I tried calling it using:

```
from fsa_test import print_function

print_function.say_hello()
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import the file that contains the functions.

```
import fsa_test import cli

cli.say_hello()
cli.hello()
```

There are ways you can import those functions into the root of the package so they are more readily available.

BTW, `from __future__ import print_function` is only necessary if you are running Python 2.

Comment: Thank you! This works! I'm just trying to learn packaging and this was my first package.

Answer (score 1):

Your execution code is incorrect. When you change to their code, everything runs fine.

```py
from fsa_test.cli import say_hello

say_hello()
```